# JSON, external API, javascript, spaces in table/field names while looping

Tags: javascript, json, api, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

I'm using an external API and there are spaces in the table and field names. For this part, it goes Body parts > Body locations
I can get console to print Body locations, but I can't send it through a for loop because of the spaces. I've played with bracket notation.
The data shows up in console, I set an alert at the beginning of the loop to see if it was getting that far. It's not. No errors or warnings.
I've been doing this for ages, I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Here's the console print of Body locations:

```
   [{"ID":16,"Name":"Abdomen, pelvis & buttocks"}, 
   {"ID":7,"Name":"Arms & shoulder"},
   {"ID":15,"Name":"Chest & back"},
   {"ID":6,"Name":"Head, throat & neck"},
   {"ID":10,"Name":"Legs"},
  {"ID":17,"Name":"Skin, joints & general"}]

   $(document).ready(function () {
    var data = null;

 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.withCredentials = false;


 xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);

        }
  });

  xhr.open("GET", "https:anguage=en-gb");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapm");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rap85");

xhr.send(data);

});

var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, i, x, txt = "";
obj = { table:"Body parts", limit: 300};
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var result = [];


for (i in myObj['Body  locations']) {
alert(it worked);



}
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "htt=en-gb");
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-api.com");
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-r13785");

 xmlhttp.send("i=" + dbParam);

 }
 }
```

Comment: Will it be possible to share the console print of your  Body locations?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Let me edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in the key should not be the problem. `myObj["body  locations"]` is an `Array`, so you best try iterating through that using `for of`. Something like:

```js
const bls = {
   "body  locations": [
     {"ID":16,"Name":"Abdomen, pelvis & buttocks"}, 
     {"ID":7,"Name":"Arms & shoulder"},
     {"ID":15,"Name":"Chest & back"},
     {"ID":6,"Name":"Head, throat & neck"},
     {"ID":10,"Name":"Legs"},
     {"ID":17,"Name":"Skin, joints & general"}
   ]
};
for (let bl of bls["body  locations"]) {
  console.info(`id: ${bl.ID}, name: ${bl.Name}`); 
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I get this error:(index):57 Uncaught TypeError: myObj.body locations is not iterable
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ((index):57)

Comment: In that case, something else, not deducible from your question, is wrong. Try exploring the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), it may simplify things.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's appreciated greatly. Sorry it didn't work. I'll check out the API right now.